# How can I access microphone in Maui WebView app?

Tags: javascript, c#, webview, permissions, maui

When trying to access the microphone via Javascript on web pages, I am continuously receiving an Access Denied error. The phone permissions are set to allow Microphone access and below is my AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MICROPHONE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Below is the javascript for recording the audio:

```js
async function setRecordButtonListeners() {
    var myRecorder = {
        objects: {
            context: null,
            stream: null,
            recorder: null
        },
        init: function () {
            if (null === myRecorder.objects.context) {
                myRecorder.objects.context = new (
                    window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext
                );
            }
        },
        start: function () {
            try {
                var options = { audio: true, video: false };
                console.log("Recording started....");
                navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(options).then(function (stream) {
                    myRecorder.objects.stream = stream;
                    myRecorder.objects.recorder = new Recorder(
                        myRecorder.objects.context.createMediaStreamSource(stream),
                        { numChannels: 1 }
                    );
                    myRecorder.objects.recorder.record();
                }).catch(function (err) { });
                writeToOutput(err);
                setRecordTimer(myRecorder);
                playPopSound();
            }
            
        },
        stop: function (listObject) {
            if (null !== myRecorder.objects.stream) {
                myRecorder.objects.stream.getAudioTracks()[0].stop();
            }
            if (null !== myRecorder.objects.recorder) {
                myRecorder.objects.recorder.stop();

                // Validate object
                /*if (null !== listObject) {*/
                    // Export the WAV file
                    myRecorder.objects.recorder.exportWAV(async function (blob) {
                        var url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL)
                            .createObjectURL(blob);

                        // Prepare the playback
                        var audioObject = document.createElement("audio");
                        audioObject.setAttribute("controls", "");
                        audioObject.setAttribute("controlsList", "noremoteplayback");
                        audioObject.setAttribute('src', url);
                        console.log("Recording stopped....");
                        playPopSound();
                        //Prepare the upload link
                        var savedToServer = await postAudioRecording(blob);
                        //var messages = document.getElementById("messages");
                        
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    };

    // Prepare the recordings list
    var listObject = document.getElementById("recordingList");

    // Prepare the record button
    document.getElementById("audioRecordButton").addEventListener("click", function () {
        // Initialize the recorder
        myRecorder.init();

        // Get the button state 
        var buttonState = !!this.getAttribute('data-recording');

        // Toggle
        if (!buttonState) {
            this.setAttribute('data-recording', 'true');
            myRecorder.start();
        } else {
            this.setAttribute('data-recording', '');
            myRecorder.stop(listObject);
        }
    });
};

var recorderTimeout;

function setRecordTimer(recorder) {
    recorderTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById("audioRecordButton").click();
        clearTimeout(recorderTimeout);
    }, 3600000);
}

async function postAudioRecording(blob) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = document.getElementById("userRecordedAudioForm");
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    formData.append("audio_data", blob, "audio.wav");
    formData.append("chatID", document.getElementById("chatIDValue").innerHTML);
    const response = await (await fetch("Chat?handler=UploadAudio", { method: "post", body: formData })).text();
    var jsonObject = JSON.parse(response);
    if (jsonObject.Success = true) {
        sendAudioMessage(jsonObject.chatID, jsonObject.messageID);
    } else {
        console.log(jsonObject);
    }
}

function stopRecording() {
    var button = document.getElementById("audioRecordButton");
    var isRecording = button.dataset.recording;
    clearTimeout(recorderTimeout);
    if (isRecording) {
        button.click();
    }   
}

function playPopSound() {
    new Audio("/audio/assets/pop.mp3").play();
}
```

Below is where I am getting an "Permission Not Allowed" error.
'''js
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(options)...catch(err)...
'''
I was expecting the Webview to act as the Chrome browser on the Android device acts (works).  What am I missing about allowing microphone permissions in the webview?

MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             x:Class="CreatorGameMobile.MainPage">

    <Page.Behaviors>
        <toolkit:StatusBarBehavior x:Name="statusBar" />
    </Page.Behaviors>

    <WebView x:Name="webview"></WebView>
    

</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        webview.Source = "https://creatorgame.app";
    }
```

MainActivity.cs

```
    protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        HandleIntent(Intent);
        CreateNotificationChannelIfNeeded();
    }
'''

Here is a page that is running the javascript above to test.

https://creatorgame.app/test
```

Comment: How can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem in detail?

Comment: I've added the complete javascript file for audio capturing.  What else would you like to see?  I want to provide whatever you need.  I am trying to have a button click on the webpage successfully access the microphone of the Maui device.  I cannot successfully get permission to the device microphone.

Comment: I can't see the other code, could you please a basic demo to so that we can test on our side?